# How to make SignalR to use the same machine throughout its' handshake?

Tags: azure, signalr, owin

We have a self-hosted OWIN service in Azure running behind a load balancer.
We're seeing cases where the 3 HTTP requests during the handshake phase (negotiate, connect, start) are routed to different machines in the service.
This causes unnecessary delay since the TLS handshake has to be performed more than once

Is there anyway to make SignalR (or the Azure LB) to keep using the same instance it started with?

Answer (score 0):

You can scale out your operation with the SignalR Azure Scale out capabilities using Azure Topics.

There is a nuget package and some minimal configuration to get it working.  Its almost turnkey if you pre-setup your Azure Service Bus Topic.

Here is some more info: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus

Make sure to not share this Topic between "Test" and "Production" environments.

Hope this helps.